# Insert checkbox in DefaultTableModel using database data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, defaulttablemodel

I'm using `DefaultTableModel` in NetBeans in showing my records from MySQL database. My data is able to display, but what I want is that to display a checkbox column at the end of my table.

I understand it needs to be overridden, but I don't know how and where to start. I see tons of example from the internet but they are using static string data, not from database. Until now I still don't get it. A help will be much appreciated.

Below is my sample code.

```
  try { 
     conn = DatabaseConnect.connect();
     ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT productID, name, quantity, price, checked FROM tbl_inventory");
     rs = ps.executeQuery();
     jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));   
  } catch(SQLException ex) {
  }
```

`jTable2` is able to display my records from `tbl_inventory`. The "checked" column from my database table `tbl_inventory` has default boolean value of 0. But I don't know how to display it as checkbox in my `JTtable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The "checked" column from my database table tbl_inventory has default boolean value of 0. But I don't know how to display it as checkbox in my JTtable.

The easiest way is to convert the "checked" data to a Boolean value as you create the TableModel. Then the default renderer/editor will be used.

```
jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

This means you can't use the above method. You need to copy the data yourself and do the conversion on the checked column.

Check out [Table From DataBase](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/). The last example `Table From Database Example` shows how to copy the data without any conversion.

You will need to modify the code with something like:

```
while (rs.next())
{
    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        if (i == ?) // convert checked column
        {
            int value = rs.getInt(i);
            row.addElement( value == 0 ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE );
        }
        else
            row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
    }

    data.addElement( row );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @camickr for your help! And the link you shared works well with my code. I was able to display the check boxes in my jTable, there's this problem I'm currently encountering though. Whenever I click the check boxes, Netbeans will show this message in the compiler output:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String

I wonder why.

Comment: Don't know what you are doing. The `getColumnClass(...)` method tells the renderer/editor what type of data is in the column. If it renders as a checkbox, then this appears to set up correctly. The editor should also work. You may have custom code I'm not aware of. I have no idea what statement is causing that exception.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. Your code works fine. I just forgot an important conversion in my jTable code, which is why I got that exception. But it's all working now.